# Ionic: position button from bottom

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

In ionic how can i put a button at some percentage from the bottom ion-content?

I've tried

```
<ion-view>
   <ion-content>
       <div class="button-bottom">
         <button class="button button-block button-energized">Button</button>
       </div>
   </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

css:

```
.button-bottom{
position: absolute;
bottom: 30%;
}
```

but the button now not take the full width.

Answer (score 5):

Try giving your container an explicit width:

```
.button-bottom{
position: absolute;
bottom: 30%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "`full`" variable  in your `button`

Ex:- `button class="button button-block button-energized" full >Button</button`>

For more reference see Ionic Documentation on UI Components in the link below.

[Ionic Full Button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#full-buttons)

Answer (score -1):

Just move the button to outside of the ion-content.

Example:

Ionic 3:

```
<ion-view>
   <ion-content>

   </ion-content>

       <div class="button-bottom">
         <button class="button button-block button-energized">Button</button>
       </div>

</ion-view>
```

Ionic 4:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Example</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

<p> your content </p>

</ion-content>

<ion-row>
  <ion-col>
    <ion-button>
      Button Bottom (Not fixed on scroll)
    </ion-button>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```